# How to fetch collection data from Shopify

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, shopify

I just started learning Shopify for a coding interview. One part of my task is to create a product section in Shopify that fetches the data from a collection and displays a product card for each item.

In the task they say that the endpoint I need is created by adding `/products.json` to the collection URL in my store. The problem is I don't really understand how I'm supposed to fetch data from a route that requires admin access. I have my function in my `Assets` folder and the section HTML in my `Sections` folder in Shopify.

I'm really getting lost here, I can't find anything about this in Shopify's documentation. Any advice would be helpful.

I tried looking for a way to get an access token or something but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have you followed Shopify's instructions? https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/auth

Answer (score 0):

To access the Admin API, you need to create an private app and install it.

The procedure is:
Go to settings -> Apps and sales channel -> Develop App -> Add Necessary permission there(for your case add product read and write) -> Then reveal the token and make sure to copy it somewhere(you can't see it again) (it'll look something like - shpat-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx)

Now you can access the Admin api with it. Just add the token with the header with the key `X-Shopify-Access-Token` : `{your access token for that shop}`

Add a curl req. For example:

```
curl -d '{"product":{"title":"Burton Custom Freestyle 151","body_html":"<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>","vendor":"Burton","product_type":"Snowboard","status":"draft"}}' \ 
-X POST "https://your-development-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/products.json" \ 
-H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}" \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json".
```

Now just follow the official docs: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-01/resources/product

Hope it helps.